# How to import java statement from notepad file and run in java program

Tags: java

this is my university's assignment, about a toll plaza simulation using Java. The question specifically asked to import the customers (the cars that went through the lanes in the toll plaza) data from a .text file. This is the the customers data that I wish to import from a .text file.

```
Queue1 lane = new Queue1(100);
lane.create(0, 0);

lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
```

If it is possible, I want to import the codes above (specifically from a .txt file) into the main method in class Queue as shown below.

```
class Queue1 {
    private int back;
    private int front;
    private int noOfCars;
    private int maxSize;
    String[] ArrayQ;
    String Item;
    public int waitingTime = 0;
    public int totalWaitingTime = 0;

    public Queue1() {

    }

    public Queue1(int a) {
        maxSize = a;
        ArrayQ = new String [maxSize];
    }


    public void create (int front, int back) {
        this.front = front;
        this.back = back;
    }


    public void ENQUEUE(String item) {
        Item = item;        
        back = back + 1;
        if(back == maxSize-1) {
            back = -1;
        }

        ArrayQ[back] = item;
        noOfCars++;

        System.out.println("Current payment type: " +item);
        if(Item == "Smart Tag") {
            waitingTime = 10;
        }
        else if(Item == "TouchNGo") {
            waitingTime = 20;
        }
        else if(Item == "Cash") {
            waitingTime = 40;
        }
        totalWaitingTime += waitingTime;
        System.out.println("Waiting time " +totalWaitingTime+ "for cars " +noOfCars);
    }

    //method DEQUEUE
    public String DEQUEUE() {
        front = front + 1;
        String temporary = ArrayQ[front];
        if(front == maxSize) {
            front = 0;
        }
        noOfCars--;
        return temporary;
    }

    //method calculate average time
    public double averageTime () {
        return (totalWaitingTime / noOfCars);
    }
}

public class Queue {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

    /*this is where the data from the .text file supposed to be.
    Queue1 lane = new Queue1(100);
        lane.create(0, 0);

        lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Smart Tag");
        lane.ENQUEUE("TouchNGo");
        lane.ENQUEUE("Cash");*/




        System.out.println("Average waiting time is: " + lane.averageTime() + "seconds");
    }
}
```

I tried to look all over the internet to do this, but most of the answers I came across is just printing texts from .txt file as an output in Java program. If this is actually the correct way to do it, please teach me how to do it in the correct manner, thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Path file = INSERT WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE;
    Queue1 lane = new Queue1(100);
    lane.create(0, 0);
    try {
       InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader =
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Leave the println to make sure you read coorectly
            System.out.println(line);
            lane.ENQUEUE(line);
    }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(file);' and 'Path file ="E:/MyTextFileLocation.text";' seems to be in need of an import statement since they triggered errors. I used 'import java.util.*;' but it doesn't seems to do the trick. Please help~

Comment: Open https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html and check the package of the Classes missing an import. As an example, you need `java.io.InputStream` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html )

Comment: @StephaneM Your sample code could be simplified using `Files.newBufferedReader(file)`.